# Sitecore item glasscast parameter value key null

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm trying to cast a Sitecore item (its in a bucket don't know if this is relevant) to a specific type:

```
var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService("master");
sitecoreService.CreateType<StaffMember>(userItem);
```

The method Createtype casts a sitecore item to the type between the <>.
However when I execute this code I get the following error:

```
value cannot be null. parameter name: key
```

I'm trying to cast to 2 different types: User and Staffmember.
When i use above code for User it works but when I cast to Staffmember i get the error

User class:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{4F6FC236-71C7-46D4-8823-09CBCDD3A233}")]
public class User
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string DatabaseId { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Identifier")]
    public virtual string Identifier { get; set; }

}
```

Staffmember class:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{717C419F-BCDF-4DC8-8AB5-29ED672DBEC4}")]
    public sealed class StaffMember 
    {
        [SitecoreId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField]
        public string DatabaseId { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Identifier")]
        public virtual string Identifier { get; set; }
    }
```

Did anyone experience this error before or know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the cast, do you use as operator. I believe this returns null if the cast fails

Comment: Can you please show us the code of the method `CreateType<>()`?

Comment: Createtype is a method inside sitecoreService of glassmapper.
I'll add some code and text.

Comment: The properties in your StaffMember class need to be virtual

Comment: Try to remove "sealed" keyword from StaffMember class, also make sure all properties are virtual

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this:

```
item.GlassCast<TModel>()
```

http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial9